# How to search the file in the Project directory in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

How to search the file in the Project directory in PyCharm?

[image]

I only can use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to find the text in the project, can not find the Project directory file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> for Windows

<kbd>Commad</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> for Mac

PyCharm has pretty extensive abilities to navigate around code. Check out the navigation section of their [windows](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard.pdf) or [mac](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard_mac.pdf) default keymappings for other cool navigation tricks.